How do I block access to a file directory in htaccess
I'm working on a website of some sorts with folders to store all the files.
The url is like this:
example.glitch.me/examplefolder/example.html

yup, i'm using glitch to build the website, i can't afford custom domains
Anyways, if I do this:
example.glitch.me/examplefolder

Here's what the file directory looks like:
file directory
I see all of the files inside this folder, and I want to prevent this in some way, I've tried the .htaccess Options All -Indexes or the Options -Indexes but it doesn't work for me, I need your help!

So what do you want to see instead? You have to respond to the request. Be it an error or other content. But you cannot just do nothing.

Add an index.html file so it will load when no html file is specified in the URL
